# How to replace the line with an exact matching of a string

Tags: linux, sed, grep, string, search

I have a file with this content:
dskldfsd.com

```
domain

domain.com

sub.domain.com

domain.main.com

anythinghere
```

I want to delete the line which contains the word `domain`. Using grep, this command find the exact line I want:

```
grep -w '^domain$' test.txt
```

But I want to delete this line that contains `domain` as a single word from the beginning to the end of the line. I want to keep the lines where the word `domain` is just part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed -i -e '/^domain$/d' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
grep -v '^domain$' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Why grep -v '^domain$'.As per question its simple grep -v 'domain' as per my understanding.

Comment: "I want to keep the lines where the word `domain` is just part of the string. "

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would want to use standard tools, you could do

```
grep -xF -v 'domain' test.txt >newtest.txt
```

The `-x` flag to `grep` forces the match to be across a whole line, and `-F` makes `grep` treat the pattern as a fixed string rather as a regular expression.  The `-v` inverts the sense of the match so that you in the end get all the lines in `test.txt` that is not just the string `domain`.  The result in written to `newtest.txt`.